# Twitter scraping using Python

Tags: python, networking, websites

I've been working on a project to reverse-enginner twitter's app to scrape public posts from Twitter using an unofficial API, with Python. (I want to create an "alternative" app, which is simply a localhost that can search for a user, and get its posts)

I've been searching and reading everything related to REST, AJAX, and the python modules requests, requests-html, BeautifulSoup, and more.

I can see when looking at twitter on the devtools (for example on Marvel's profile page) that the only relevant requests being sent (by POST and GET) are the following: client_event.json and UserTweets?variables=... .
I understood that these are the relevant messages being received by cleaning the network tab and recording only when I scroll down and load new tweets - these are the only messages that came up which aren't random videos (I cleaned the search using -video -init -csp_report -config -ondemand -like -pageview -recommendations -prefetch -jot -key_live_kn -svg -jpg -jpeg -png -ico -analytics -loader -sharedCore -Hebrew).

I am new to this field, so I am probably doing something wrong. I can see on UserTweets the response I'm looking for - a beautiful JSON with all the data I need - but I am unable, no matter how much I've been trying to, to access it.

I tried different modules and different headers, and I get nothing. I DON'T want to use Selenium since it's tiresome, and I know where the data I need is stored.
[image: The JSON I want]

I've been trying to send a GET reuest to:
https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/vamMfA41UoKXUmppa9PhSw/UserTweets?variables=%7B%22userId%22%3A%2215687962%22%2C%22count%22%3A20%2C%22cursor%22%3A%22HBaIgLLN%2BKGEryYAAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22withHighlightedLabel%22%3Atrue%2C%22withTweetQuoteCount%22%3Atrue%2C%22includePromotedContent%22%3Atrue%2C%22withTweetResult%22%3Afalse%2C%22withUserResults%22%3Afalse%2C%22withVoice%22%3Afalse%2C%22withNonLegacyCard%22%3Atrue%7D

by doing:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = session.get('https://twitter.com/i/api/graphql/vamMfA41UoKXUmppa9PhSw/UserTweets?variables=%7B%22userId%22%3A%2215687962%22%2C%22count%22%3A20%2C%22cursor%22%3A%22HBaIgLLN%2BKGEryYAAA%3D%3D%22%2C%22withHighlightedLabel%22%3Atrue%2C%22withTweetQuoteCount%22%3Atrue%2C%22includePromotedContent%22%3Atrue%2C%22withTweetResult%22%3Afalse%2C%22withUserResults%22%3Afalse%2C%22withVoice%22%3Afalse%2C%22withNonLegacyCard%22%3Atrue%7D')
response.html.render()
s = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, 'lxml')
```

but I get back an HTML script that either says Chromium is unsupported, or just a static page without the javascript updating the DOM.

All help appreciated.

Thank you